# How to zero values in dataframe based on values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have two dataframes of the same size, one with values:

```
d1 = {'values1': [1, 1,2,2], 'values2': [10, 50,200,100]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
```

And a dataframe of booleans:

```
d2 = {'boolean1': [True, False,True,True], 'boolean2': [False, False,False,True]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

How can I repplace values in `df1` to zeros where booleans are `True`?

The result I am looking for is:

```
r = {'values1': [0, 1,0,0], 'values2': [10, 50,200,0]}
result = pd.DataFrame(data=r)
```

Comment: Do you want to replace in place? `df1[df2.to_numpy()] = 0`

Answer (score 4):

Because differnt columns names between both DataFrames use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with converting `df2` to numpy array:

```
result = df1.mask(df2.to_numpy(), 0)
print (result)
   values1  values2
0        0       10
1        1       50
2        0      200
3        0        0
```

If set columns names in boolean DataFrame - same columns in both DataFrames is not necessary convert to numpy array:

```
result = df1.mask(df2.set_axis(df1.columns, inplace=False, axis=1), 0)
print (result)

   values1  values2
0        0       10
1        1       50
2        0      200
3        0        0
```